# Credential safety in AWS Cognito client App

Tags: amazon-web-services, webpack, amazon-cognito

I am using the AWS Cognito service for user management and as per the tutorial by AWS i am using Webpack. All my data and functions I define are in `entry.js` and then I run the `npm run build` which creates a file names `my-app.js` which I have to include in my html file as JavaScript.

Now the problem is that I have the `UserPool ID`, `Client ID`, `IdentityPool ID` and some information which cannot to shared with the client for security purpose.

The `my-app.js` has to be included in the HTML file hence exposing the credentials, is there any way I can hide my credentials or any other way anyone can suggest? I am new to this.

Answer (score 1):

You have to provide the UserPoolId, ClientId and IdentityPoolId when using the AWS Cognito API - they are all required fields in various methods. So you will have to have that information somewhere in the client. You could try to obfuscate it if you want, but that probably isn't worth the effort.

From a security perspective what are you concerned about? The official AWS docs basically imply that it is OK to embed these values client side. I have not seen anything from Amazon that describes a best practice relating to trying to hide/secure the user/identity pool ids. Even if an attacker has the UserPoolId and ClientId, they would still need a username/password to access your service.

Comment: With the UserPool and ClientID anyone can create users in my UserPool and with IdentityPool ID they can also use the Sign In functionality by using my UserPool, that's my concern.

Comment: If you have a signup form on a public website, anyone could look at the HTML, figure out the signup details and create themselves an account, then login. What is the difference?

Comment: The details of my UserPool and ClientID are not in HTML form, they are in javascript. One cannot create an account just by accessing gmail, they need the credentials and they are exposed in my JavaScript.

Comment: AWS Amplify, Amazon's front end library, explicitly says to embed the Cognito parameters in your JS. See https://aws-amplify.github.io/amplify-js/media/authentication_guide.

Answer (score 0):

You can check "AWS secret manager" service which is launched recently.
I have not used it so far, but you can share your experience.

Reading through introduction looks like it can solve your use case.

https://aws.amazon.com/secrets-manager/